# Searching for a all can do database program

Tags: sql, database

Is there a program to create all models in a database in one, from conceptual, relational and physical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Paradigm is a tool that I've used for designing **Conceptual**, **Logical**, and **Physical** ER Models.  They have free community [edition](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/community.jsp) that comes with a lot less tools and functionality, but for basic projects it will get the job done.  Microsoft Visio is another tool you can draw just about anything in. However, it's not as intuitive as Visual Paradigm is when you are creating database model.